# Problems passing array via AJAX to server

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Using the following code:

##### Service-side

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetValidateProductsAsync(IEnumerable<string> products)
{
    // ...
}
```

##### Client-side

```
var products = [];
$checkedItems.each(function () {
    products.push($(this).closest('tr').data('product'));
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '?handler=ValidateProducts',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'products': products },
})
.done(function (response) {
    // TODO:
})
.fail(function (response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
})
```

My handler is called, but the `products` parameter is an empty collection (not null).

The query sent to the server is:

```
?handler=ValidateProducts&products[]=40 70 SAND&products[]=SAND FRACING 100 MESH
```

How can I pass a string array like this and have it show up on the server?

#### Update 1:

I tried changing the JavaScript to use `data: products`, but that caused other problems. My query string was `?handler=ValidateProducts&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=`, and the `products` parameter was empty on the server side.

#### Update 2:

madreflection's suggestion of using `[FromQuery(Name = "products[]")] IEnumerable<string> products` causes the code to work. But I'm not sure why it's needed. I was under the impression I'm doing standard stuff.

Comment: You sending object, but your controller method is accepting collection. Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72003870/14095048 all what you need here. But you need to use `[FromBodyAttribute]` instead of `[FromForm]`.

Comment: `[FromBody]` won't work for a GET request. The browser simply will not even attempt to make a GET request with a body (it produces an error), even though ASP.NET Core supports it.

Comment: Based on how it's constructing the query string, try putting `[FromQuery("products[]")]` on the parameter.

Comment: Oh, sure. I didn't noticed that. But here is the question why GET method used. I think there is way how to use query for object, but not sure about collection.

Comment: @madreflection: Doing that causes it to work. But not really sure why. I didn't think I was doing anything non-standard.

Comment: @SergeyNazarov: I tried `data: products` instead. That didn't work, but I had some different issues. The query string looked like `?handler=ValidateProducts&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=`.

Comment: @JonathanWood: "Non-standard" depends on your perspective. For jQuery, producing the name with the brackets is normal. For ASP.NET Core, it's not expecting them to be that way. Neither is "standard", just different ways of designing them. If you're using URL-encoded form data, the way jQuery is producing the names works with the way the MVC data binder works.

Comment: That brings us to Sergey's question, why use GET and not POST? Yes, GET works as long as you don't exceed the limit of a query string. For an array that could potentially be any size, that could be a problem. If you can't control that, it's better to use POST so you're not limited in how much you can receive in that array.

Comment: @madreflection: Initially, I wanted to use POST. But then I run into complexities related to anti-forgery tokens. I modified my code to eliminate any duplicates, so now I'm confident the list won't ever get too long.

Comment: Fair enough. As long as you've taken that into consideration, you're good to go.

Comment: @SergeyNazarov: Using POST raises complexities related to anti-forgery tokens. I made some changes so now I'm confident the list won't get too long. I'd rather use POST though. I also tried using an object like your link explained but wasn't able to get that to work and that answer didn't include AJAX/JavaScript.

Comment: As I said, I didn't noticed GET, my apologies. For me, ordinary thing to use POST, when I'm passing object or collection. Hope, @madreflection 's answer helps!

Comment: FWIW, my UI developer is using the POST endpoints I provided and there's none of that anti-forgery stuff getting in the way. Page handlers are nice because they keep things together in the Razor Page, but if they're preventing you from using something that's technically what you need, you need to rethink your architecture.

Comment: @madreflection: Well, I did try POST initially and it kept getting 400 errors. There are [workarounds](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/336/ajax-posts-in-razor-pages-and-http-400-errors). It just seemed to be adding complexity I didn't need.

Comment: As far as I can tell, from what you've said, you still did it in a page handler. I'm talking about using a Web API controller. You need something that isn't trying to fit the data into a `<form>`-based paradigm.

Comment: @madreflection: Okay, just explaining why I had to deal with anti-forgery stuff. Yes, I understand you're recommending I consider an API. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use post method to pass list with ajax to backend,and for razor page,you need to add an antiforgery token for post request,here is a demo:

cshtml:

```
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken
    @section Scripts{
     <script>
        ar products = [];
    $checkedItems.each(function () {
        products.push($(this).closest('tr').data('product'));
    });
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '?handler=ValidateProducts',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
        data:JSON.stringify(products ),
    })
    .done(function (response) {
        // TODO:
    })
    .fail(function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    })
     </script>
    }
```

cshtml.cs:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostValidateProductsAsync([FromBody]IEnumerable<string> products)
{
    // ...
}
```